# is it possible to find an object from an array and return an object not his reference?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to find an object from an array and return an object not his reference?

`let found = this.clonedAllIconsMatching.find((obj) => obj.id == header.id);`

the found variable is a reference I need to have an object,
I want a copy of the object, and I want to change only the properties of the found object, not the object contained in the array.

Comment: All object values in JavaScript are references, all the time.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to clone the object into another instance?  It's not really clear what you're trying to do or why.

Comment: in OOP "clone" means: make a copy of the object. So if you call a function starting with "clone", you should expect a copy and not the original object. Try calling a function, which does not start with "clone".

Comment: @David I want a copy of the object found, and I want to change only  the properties of this object, not the object contained in the array

Comment: @slacky82: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/328193)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES2018, you can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax): `{...obj}`. Otherwise, you can iterate through and copy the keys and values:

```js
// obj is the object to clone
var o = {}; // The copy
for(var i in obj){
    o[i] = obj[i];
}
```